# Pulling User Input from txt File

Tags: c#, .net, list, streamreader

I created an app that pulls user input from a txt file (college, city). A random school will show if the user types "random college". The loop seems to be skipping the part that checks the list for the user's input.
Criteria:

1. If school matches txt file, display school and city back to the user
2. If school does not match txt file, error message is displayed
3. The user could put in as many schools as they wish, exit by typing "x"

   ```
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;

   namespace The_College_Search_From_and_Console_App
   {
        class Program
        {

        static List<string> SchoolCityList = new List<string>();
        static Dictionary<string, string> SchoolCityDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            //Prompts the user to enter a university or type "random college". (added 'Utah' because thats all thats in the list)
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Utah University or type 'random college' (press x to exit)");
            Console.WriteLine();

            //string CollegeSelection = Console.ReadLine();
            string CollegeSelection = string.Empty;

            //ReadSchoolList();

            while (CollegeSelection != "x")
             {

                CollegeSelection = Console.ReadLine();

                //Nothing in the list contains "random college" so this should work
                if (CollegeSelection.Contains("random college"))
                {
                    //empty WriteLine() function to add spacing
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    //Creates the list and returns a random school
                    Console.WriteLine("Results:");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    RandoSchool();
                   }
                    else if (SchoolCityDict.TryGetValue(CollegeSelection.ToUpper(),out string city))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{CollegeSelection}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"{city}");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CollegeSelection == "x")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();

                        //notify the user that their entry does not exist
                        Console.WriteLine($"The College '{CollegeSelection}' does not exist in the database.");
                    }

                }
                 //Prompts the user to enter a university or type "random college". (added 'Utah' because thats all thats in the list)
                 Console.WriteLine();
                 Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Utah University or type 'random college' (press x to exit)");
                 Console.WriteLine();
             }       

        }

        //This will create and format the list that will be used in the main method
        private static void ReadSchoolList()
        {

            //Create a StreamReader variable for the schoollist.txt file
            StreamReader inputfile;

            try
            {
                //Uses OpenText function to read the schoollist.txt file from its location in the python folder
                inputfile = File.OpenText(@"C:\{file directory goes here}");

                string tempread = "";


                //Will loop through the list until it reaches the end
                while (!inputfile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //ReadLine() Function will read through each line of the file
                    tempread = inputfile.ReadLine();

                    SchoolCityList.Add(tempread.ToUpper());

                    //Split the line items at the comma
                    string[] tempSchoolCity = tempread.Split(',');

                    //Inserts the file line items into dictionary. Sets the values in uppercase. [0] for left of comma, [1] for right
                    SchoolCityDict.Add(tempSchoolCity[0].ToUpper(), tempSchoolCity[1].ToUpper());

                }

                //Closes the file after the loop
                inputfile.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //writes a message that explains the current exeption 
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                //Empty write line function for spacing
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void RandoSchool()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();

            int totalColleges = rand.Next(SchoolCityDict.Count);
            string randCollege = SchoolCityDict.ElementAt(totalColleges).Key;

            if (SchoolCityDict.TryGetValue(randCollege, out string city))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Random College: {randCollege},{city}");
            }
        }

      }
   }
   ```

**Sample Data:**
Bridgerland Technical College, Logan
Davis Technical College, Kaysville
Dixie Technical College, St. George
Mountainland Technical College, Orem
Ogden–Weber Technical College, Ogden
Southwest Technical College, Cedar City
Tooele Technical College, Tooele
Uintah Basin Technical College, Roosevelt

Comment: This is a **great** opportunity to learn how to debug code using the **[awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Please add some sample data to your post.

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't load the data from the text file because you commented it out: `//ReadSchoolList();` After that you haven't properly split the data. Using StreamReader is ok, but [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-6.0) or [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-6.0) may be easier. The best thing to do is to "step" through your code with pencil/pen and paper to see what is happening - this is what you're going to have to do on your exam.